# Cauchy's Integral Theorem. Does it have to be a "curved" closed contour?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

My question is (e).

I know f is analytic by the Cauchy-Riemann condition for (a).

For the results of (b), (c), and (d), I get 4/3, 8/3 + 2i, 1/3 + i5/3.

So, to make the closed loop, I did (b)+(c)-(d), but it does not give me 0. Cauchy's integral formula says it should be 0 tho.

What did I wrong?

Comment: have you noticed that $f(z)=z^2+2z$ ?

Answer (score 1):

When you integrate in $c)$, multiply by $i$, the derivative of $z(t)$.  In $d)$, multiply by $(1+i)$.  Recall that the line integral is $\int f(z(t))\color {blue}{z'(t)}\rm dt$.

(Note also you made another mistake on the third integral.)

You can check that $4/3+i(8/3+2i)-(1+i)(1+5/3i)=0$ gives zero.

Comment: The important thing is that segment [0,1+i] should be traversed in the opposite direction (explaining the "minus" sign) in order to preserve a direct (= anticlockwise) general orientation.

Comment: @JeanMarie that is certainly true.

Comment: My comment was aimed at the asker, in order he/she gets the essential message. I have also made him/her the remark that $f(z)=z^2+2z$ which is simpler to tackle.

Comment: Astute observation.   @JeanMarie